# How to use the GDB console in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way how I can access gdb's console in Eclipse? I would like to just be able to set breakpoints with the mouse and then use the console for debugging.

Answer (score 21):

You must click **here** [image]

Next select one with ***gdb** [image]

Now you can write GDB commands in console **example**:

[image]

Comment: I just updated from mars to neon and the gdb command log window seems to be gone. did it move somewhere else?

Comment: never mind I found it, it's a new view called "debugger console"

Comment: More specifically, to get the gdb view in Eclipse Neon, go to Window -> Show View -> Other -> Debug -> Debugger Console

Answer (score 9):

First of all, you need to install CDT plugin. Then, you can debug C++ application like Java application in Eclipse.

If you want gdb console, push 'Display Selected Console' in Console view in Debug perspective.

You can choose '[Your App name][C/C++ Application]gdb' entry, and then you can type gdb instruction(i.e. print this) in Console View.

Comment: That sounds fun...almost as fun as reading a small tutorial on how to use gdb in the terminal...>_<

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write in the console window and gdb answers. (You have to choose the right console window from the chooser in the top right edge of the console view).

Unfortunately the console is quite limited: gdb answers to command, but important features like tab-completion do not work.

Comment: I figured out that I can adjust the settings when going to Debug->Debug Configurations, however I have no idea what to choose. Also It crashed when I tried to display an array by right clicking on in in the variable window and then choosing "Display as Array"

Answer (score 2):

**Window > Show view > "Debugger Console"** is the right way as of Eclipse CDT 4.7.0.

You can then type certain commands like `print` on the console and they will be evaluated.

Other more "active" commands like `continue` have no effect however.

Mentioned [on this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387587/use-gdb-console-in-eclipse#comment76689772_18103270).