# Exploring variables of complex types in Eclipse debugging C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

How do I explore the content of a variable of complex type, say, a multimap where key and value are also of some complex type, like some classes.

Debug can only show the value of the pointer, but not the content of the instance of multimap. I know in gdb, if you have a variable var, and it has a method, say, getAddress(), then you can do something like: p var->getAddress() to see the value retured by that function, Can I do something similar in Eclipse Debug?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Eclipse is just a fancy shell above GDB, so everything you can do in GDB is also possible to do in the Eclipse debugger.

Comment: Also, if you do some searching, you will find Python scripts for GDB to show the standard library types in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

1. Here is a way to use standard gdb commands from within Eclipse (a console where you can type them in):
   [Use gdb console in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387587/use-gdb-console-in-eclipse)
2. Here are the scripts Joachim mentioned (multimap is supported): http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport